# An error in the gradient of marginal likelihood in "Gaussian Processes in Machine Learning"?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

Could there be a mistake in Rasmussen & Williams 2006: Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning?

It seems to me that ${\partial W \over \partial \hat{f_i}} = - \frac{\partial^3}{\partial f^3_i}\log p(y|\hat{f})$, so the minus sign in the last term should change to +. Or am I wrong?

[image]